# Linkedin API V2 query by VanityName with ampersand doesn't work

Tags: linkedin-api

Working example: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=apple`

Basically this is working for any other company, except if it has a `&` in the name, for example:

cannot use this vanity name (doesn't seem to be a url encode problem on the client side):

`johnson-&-johnson` or `johnson-%26-johnson`

The error is always the same:

```
serviceCode: 100
status: 403
message: Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/-johnson]
```

This is not a permission problem, its working with any other vanity name.

In the response the `uri` seems to be messed up: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?-johnson=&q=vanityName&vanityName=johnson-`

It should equal the request which is `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=johnson-%26-johnson`.

Also [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http) doesn't seem to mention this use case.

Some other examples that work

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=johnson-controls-middle-east-africa
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=lowe's-home-improvement
```